# How to get all installations when using Azure Notification Hubs installation model?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Using `NotificationHubClient` I can get all [registered devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.getallregistrationsasync.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(System.String,System.Int32)) using `GetAllRegistrationsAsync()`. But if I do not use the registration model but the installation model instead, how can I get all installations? There are methods to retrieve a [specific installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.getinstallationasync.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.GetInstallationAsync(System.String)) but none to get everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, as of July 2016 there's no way to get all installations for a hub. In the future, the product team is planning to add this feature to the installations model, but it will work in a different way. Instead of making it a runtime operation, you'll provide your storage connection string and you'll get a blob with everything associated with the hub.

Comment: Is...this still coming?

Comment: @gorillapower, according to the product team, it's still in the backlog. But, unfortunately, there is no ETA on when it's going to be available.

Comment: So how does one update a template for all installations?

Comment: Is there a github ticket open for this we can upvote and put pressure on for a quicker resolution?

Comment: @DeanPuckett, I don't think so, unfortunately. I am not aware of the NH team using GH (or other publicly-facing means) to lay out plans and track progress.

Comment: I found the NotificationHub .NET team on Github and have raised an issue ticket with them. Please comment and contribute to get this sorted.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/issues/143

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for visiting an old thread... but in theory you could use the GetAllRegistrationsAsyc to get all the installations.  I guess this will return everything without an installation id as well, but you could just ignore those if you choose.

Could look something like this

```
        var allRegistrations = await _hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);
        var continuationToken = allRegistrations.ContinuationToken;
        var registrationDescriptionsList = new List<RegistrationDescription>(allRegistrations);
        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken))
        {
            var otherRegistrations = await _hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(continuationToken, 0);
            registrationDescriptionsList.AddRange(otherRegistrations);
            continuationToken = otherRegistrations.ContinuationToken;
        }

        // Put into DeviceInstallation object
        var deviceInstallationList = new List<DeviceInstallation>();

        foreach (var registration in registrationDescriptionsList)
        {
            var deviceInstallation = new DeviceInstallation();

            var tags = registration.Tags;
            foreach(var tag in tags)
            {
                if (tag.Contains("InstallationId:"))
                {
                    deviceInstallation.InstallationId = new Guid(tag.Substring(tag.IndexOf(":")+1));
                }
            }
            deviceInstallation.PushHandle = registration.PnsHandle;
            deviceInstallation.Tags = new List<string>(registration.Tags);

            deviceInstallationList.Add(deviceInstallation);
        }
```

I am not suggesting this to be the cleanest chunk of code written, but it does the trick for us.  We only use this for debugging type purposes anyways

Comment: How do we get the installation Platform information from the registration?