# How can I get a list of my Installations in Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to figure out how to use the recommended approach from Microsoft and use the Installation Model to handle registrations.

I want to be able to get some information about the installations that should have been saved and I see that there are two methods that could be useful

`GetInstallation(string installationId)` and `GetInstallationAsync(string installationId)`

Problem is that when making at call to any of them I never get a response back. I can't figure out what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511069/182371) (that still holds true as of Nov 2016):

> ... there's no way to get all installations for a hub. In the future, the
>   product team is planning to add this feature to the installations
>   model, but it will work in a different way. Instead of making it a
>   runtime operation, you'll provide your storage [account] connection string and
>   you'll get a blob with everything associated with the hub.

Comment: Actually I noticed that question as well. He's asking for a way to get all installations. But if you already know one installationId. Shouldn't the methods GetInstallation and GetInstallationAsync work?

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood your question. Do you see your installations [using Cloud Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer/#self-diagnose-tips)? When you say 'never get response back' do you mean the method never returns or that the response is empty?